# I can't use the right function in MS Access

Tags: vba, ms-access

I can't use the right function in MS Access text box with this code :

```
=Right("computer",2)
```

or

```
=Right("computer";2)
```

BUT The other functions work

[image: error code]

Comment: What is output from function `shamsi()`? Are they string or numbers or dates? Show your input data and expected output.

Comment: I think `shamsi()` need some argument as input. May be you are missing that argument like `=Right(shamsi(Textbox1),2)`

Comment: The output of shamsi() is 14010315

Comment: Check your references - you must have an invalid "Missing" reference - check in VBA Editor | Tools | References

Comment: Where are you using this? As Control Source or in some event code?

Comment: I used it in a form text box

Comment: Which property of the textbox did you type this formula? ControlSource (it works there)? Name of the textbox (it works ok there, too).

Comment: Do you have a Function called `Right` in your MSAccess VBA Code base? Can you try one more time with `=Right$("computer", 5)`

Comment: I have not any other Right function and I tested the Right$() function more and more but it doesn't work at all BUT the single input functions work !!!

Answer (score 0):

Try

`=Right(format$(shamsi()),2)`

Comment: Thank you but doesn't work

Comment: Replace colon , with semicolon ;
It worked for me that way =>  =Right(shamsi();2)

Comment: Didn't work again

Comment: where does the `shamsi` function come from? Was it deleted from original question?

Comment: The right() function doesn't work at all even in :  =Right("computer",2)
or

=Right("computer";2)

Comment: In this case I doubt that Ms Access file itself is corrupt. Try the function in another new file and if it works then transfer your work to this new file and delete the old one